# Page model losing it's assigned object value. ASP.NET Razor Page

Tags: asp.net-core, properties, razor-pages

When I select item then **OnGetDetails(int id, int toggle)** method is activated and loads object from DB to property.

```
[BindProperty]
public Creature Creature { get; set; }

public void OnGetDetails(int id, int toggle){
            Creature = new GetCreature(_ctx).Get(id);
}
```

```
public Creature Get(int id){            
return _ctx.Creatures.Include(i => i.Items).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
} // Get()
```

I have verified in debugger that it assigns the object correctly.

But when I want to use that object's property in OnPost method then debugger shows it as null. As if in the meantime reassigned a value to the property as an empty object. I checked that the default OnGet method is not activated. I just do not understand why value is lost and how to prevent it from happening.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostDeleteItemAsync(int id){
          CreatureItem item = Creature.Items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ItemId == id);
          if (item == null) return RedirectToPage("Creature");

          await new EditCreature(_ctx).DeleteItem(Creature, id);
          return Redirect(UrlString);
}
```

Tried workaround with form but I was only able to pass object's id not the whole object.

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="Creature.Id" /> works

<input type="hidden" asp-for="Creature" /> don't work
```

Git:
https://github.com/Mlorism/LastTemple/blob/master/LastTemple/Pages/Manage/Creature.cshtml 
https://github.com/Mlorism/LastTemple/blob/master/LastTemple/Pages/Manage/Creature.cshtml.cs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Properties of `PageModel` are not stored between requests. Even if you have a property assigned on `GET` request it won't be there on `POST` request because these are two different requests. During `POST` `Creature` property is null because it's being [bound](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/model-binding) from request but no data was sent. And your "workaround" addresses this issue, it sends data on request to fill `Creature` property with values. Moreover this is **not** a workaround, this is how things are supposed to work.

If you want a property to be instantiated you need to pass some values via form, or query parameters if it's a `GET` request.